# Emulator error in different project

Tags: android

I made a basic Android project, as described here: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app

When I run the application, I get these error messages:

```
Emulator: :ERROR:./android/qt/qt_setup.cpp:28:Qt library not found at 
$PATH_OF_ANOTHER_ANDROID_PROJECT/emulator/lib64/qt/lib

Emulator: Could not launch '$PATH_OF_ANOTHER_ANDROID_PROJECT/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-i386': No such file or directory

Emulator: Process finished with exit code 2
```

Here, `PATH_OF_ANOTHER_ANDROID_PROJECT` is the file system location of another project.

Why is Android Studio searching for the emulator in another project rather than somewhere in this project or in some global location?

Any ideas about how this issue could be solved?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my "Android SDK Location" was set to another project (`$PATH_OF_ANOTHER_ANDROID_PROJECT`).

The solution was to change my Android SDK Location.

The solution on Mac, in Android Studio:

1.`Cmd-Shift-A`

2.Write `Android SDK`

3.Select `Android SDK Location`

4.Change the field to something like `/Users/myUser/Library/Android/sdk`.

Comment: In my case, this SDK location was already properly set, yet the error is the same.